# Android wait for WiFi scan to finish

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi

i'm trying to wait for the wifi scan to finish in the broadcast receiver!.

I have 1 Activty (ChooseActivity extends Activity) and 1 class (Scan).

In my Activity i call Scan class to scan wifi and return boolean (true) when finish, here is the code.

My purpose is to separate the scan of my activity because i call scan class in several places.

```
public class ChooseActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private int idMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose);

    idMap = this.getIntent().getExtras().getInt("ID_MAP");

    ((Button)this.findViewById(R.id.scan_button)).setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.scan_button:
        Scan scan = new Scan();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " "+scan.scanHotspots(idMap), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        break;
    }   
}
}
```

And here is my Scan class

```
public boolean scanHotspots(int idMap){

    wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    wifiManager.startScan();

    receiver = new Receiver();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
    context.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);

    //HERE I WANT STOP EXECUTION TO WAIT test VAIRABLE CHANGE STATUS    

    return test;
}


public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION))
        {   
            test=true;  
        }
    }       
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: "test" is just an exemple, i want to return list of hotspot detect in broadcastReceiver to "ChooseActivity".

But in "scanHotspots" function i want to wait scanResult to return list!

Thanks for help